# Implicit function theorem, system of equations

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Problem statement**

Given the function:
$$F(x,y,z) = (x^2y^3 + yz^3, xy^2 + y^3z^3) = (0,0)$$

Show that $F(x,y,z)$ is an implicit function $f: \mathbb{R} ^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, that is, $(x,y)^T = f(z)$, at the point $(1,1,-1)$ and find $f'(-1)$ if it exists.

**Attempt at a solution**

Define $g(x,y,z) = x^2y^3 + yz^3 = 0$ and $h(x,y,z) = xy^2 + y^3z^3 = 0$. Then
$$\begin{align} z_{x_1} = -\frac{g_x}{g_z} &= -\frac{2xy^3}{3yz^2} \\ 
z_{y_1} = -\frac{g_y}{g_z} &= -\frac{3x^2y^2 + z^3}{3yz^2} \\
z_{x_2} = -\frac{h_x}{h_z} &= -\frac{y^2}{3y^3z^2} \\ 
z_{y_2} = -\frac{h_y}{h_z} &= -\frac{2xy + 3y^2z^3}{3y^3z^2} \end{align}$$

At the point $(1,1,-1)$ both $g_z$ and $h_z$ are non-zero so $F(x,y,z)$ is an implicit function. And now I'm stuck because plugging $(1,1,-1)$ into the equations of above yields different results for $f'(-1)$ which makes me believe I've done something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I think I get it now. I didn't need to find $z_x$ etc as from above but rather find: $$\begin{align} \frac{dz}{dx} &= -\left. \frac{\frac{d(f,g)}{d(x,y)}}{\frac{d(f,g)}{d(z,y)}} \right| _{(1,1,-1)} \\\end{align}$$

Am I now on the right track?